# PHPMailer no arroja error, siempre dice que se envía el correo

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un `php` realizado con `phpmailer` para restablecer la contraseña desde una app, se ejecuta perfectamente cuando se ingresa el correo adecuado, y cuando el correo no existe en la base de datos no lo envía, el problema esta en que siempre muestra el mensaje que se envió correctamente, no arroja ningún error.

```
<?php 
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
require 'Exception.php';
require 'OAuth.php';

require 'ventor/autoloader.php';

include 'conexion.php';

if($_POST){

    $correo = $_POST["correo"];       
    $pregunta = $_POST["pregunta"];

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios_noadministradores WHERE correo = '".$correo."' AND pregunta = '".$pregunta."'") or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if($count>0) 
{      

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

try 
{   
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
'verify_peer' => false,
'verify_peer_name' => false,
'allow_self_signed' => true
)
    );
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;   
    $mail->isSMTP();   
    $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";  
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'user@user';
    $mail->Password = 'pass***************';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";      

    $mail->setFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'Construcciones Metalurgicas C.A');
    $mail->addAddress($correo, $correo);

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Reestablecimiento de Contraseña';
    $mail->Body = "Hola, <strong>{$row['nombre']}</strong>, te saludamos desde Construcciones Metalurgicas C.A para informarte que tu solicitud de reestablecimiento de contraseña se ha procesado con exito. <br><br>Tus datos son los siguientes:<br>Usuario: {$row['usuario']}<br>Contraseña: {$row['clave']}<br> Respuesta de pregunta de seguridad: {$row['pregunta']}<br><br> Muchas gracias por elegir nuestros servicios!!! <strong><br><br><br>Ing. German Micco <br> Analista de Sistemas <br> germanmicco10@gmail.com</strong><br> ESTA ES UNA CUENTA NO MONITOREADA, POR FAVOR, ABSTENGASE DE RESPONDER O HACER LLAMADOS A NOMBRES DE ESTA CUENTA, SI NECESITA PRESENTAR ALGUN RECLAMO O REQUERIMIENTO, POR FAVOR HACERLO A TRAVES DE LA APLICACIÓN OFICIAL DE CONTRUMECA";
    $mail->AltBody = "Hola, <strong>{$row['nombre']}</strong>, te saludamos desde Construcciones Metalurgicas C.A para informarte que tu solicitud de reestablecimiento de contraseña se ha procesado con exito. <br><br>Tus datos son los siguientes:<br>Usuario: {$row['usuario']}<br>Contraseña: {$row['clave']} <br><br> Muchas gracias por elegir nuestros servicios!!! <strong><br><br><br>Ing. German Micco <br> Analista de Sistemas <br> germanmicco10@gmail.com</strong><br> ESTA ES UNA CUENTA NO MONITOREADA, POR FAVOR, ABSTENGASE DE RESPONDER O HACER LLAMADOS A NOMBRES DE ESTA CUENTA, SI NECESITA PRESENTAR ALGUN RECLAMO O REQUERIMIENTO, POR FAVOR HACERLO A TRAVES DE LA APLICACIÓN OFICIAL DE CONTRUMECA";

    $mail->send();

    echo 'Tu contraseña ha sido enviada correctamente a tu correo';
    }catch (Exception $e) 
    {
    echo 'El correo no pudo ser enviado';
    echo 'Error: ' .$mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

    }

    }

    ?>
```

Les agradecería sugerencias, cabe destacar que soy nuevo con `php`, no he podido dar con la solución. Intente con un un `input` tanto desde `html` como desde mi app en `android studio` para descartar,  llegue a la conclusión que el problema esta en este `php`.

Comment: Evita publicar datos sensibles en tus preguntas _en este sitio y en cualquier otro de Internet_

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `$count` en los casos en los que das por supuesto que el correo no existe y por tanto no debería enviarse?

Comment: @DjCrazy si lo se, esos datos no son validos, los modifique.

Comment: es tan simple como`if($mail->send()){ echo 'Tu contraseña ha sido enviada correctamente a tu correo';}else{echo 'Error: ' .$mail->ErrorInfo; }` ya que catch jamas se ejecutar si no hay un error que evite la ejecucion del codigo.

Comment: @Bryro gracias por el aporte, pero no encuentro donde ubicarlo, intente reemplazando el catch pero claro me dice que tiene que haber un catch si hay un try.

Comment: solo remplazas la linea que dice `$mail->send();` con el codigo que te puse arriba

Comment: nada amigo, con solo reemplazar esa linea por el código sigue igual

Comment: y al correr el php desde localhost en el navegador pues sale en blanco, sin respuesta

Answer (score 0):

No se si aún te sirve la respuesta, pero creo que así debe funcionar...

Yo no lo haría con `try` `catch` sino validando al final, si el email no es enviado que muestre el error, pero si es enviado, que muestre el mensaje de envío exitoso.

```
<?php 
    require 'PHPMailer.php';
    require 'SMTP.php';
    require 'Exception.php';
    require 'OAuth.php';

    require 'ventor/autoloader.php';

    include 'conexion.php';

    if($_POST){

        $correo = $_POST["correo"];       
        $pregunta = $_POST["pregunta"];

        $query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios_noadministradores WHERE correo = '".$correo."' AND pregunta = '".$pregunta."'") or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

        if($count>0) {      

            $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

            $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;   
            $mail->isSMTP();   
            $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";  
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = 'user@user';
            $mail->Password = 'pass***************';
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  
            $mail->Mailer = "smtp";      

            $mail->setFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'Construcciones Metalurgicas C.A');
            $mail->addAddress($correo, $correo);

            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = 'Reestablecimiento de Contraseña';
            $mail->Body = "Hola, <strong>{$row['nombre']}</strong>, te saludamos desde Construcciones Metalurgicas C.A para informarte que tu solicitud de reestablecimiento de contraseña se ha procesado con exito. <br><br>Tus datos son los siguientes:<br>Usuario: {$row['usuario']}<br>Contraseña: {$row['clave']}<br> Respuesta de pregunta de seguridad: {$row['pregunta']}<br><br> Muchas gracias por elegir nuestros servicios!!! <strong><br><br><br>Ing. German Micco <br> Analista de Sistemas <br> germanmicco10@gmail.com</strong><br> ESTA ES UNA CUENTA NO MONITOREADA, POR FAVOR, ABSTENGASE DE RESPONDER O HACER LLAMADOS A NOMBRES DE ESTA CUENTA, SI NECESITA PRESENTAR ALGUN RECLAMO O REQUERIMIENTO, POR FAVOR HACERLO A TRAVES DE LA APLICACIÓN OFICIAL DE CONTRUMECA";
            $mail->AltBody = "Hola, <strong>{$row['nombre']}</strong>, te saludamos desde Construcciones Metalurgicas C.A para informarte que tu solicitud de reestablecimiento de contraseña se ha procesado con exito. <br><br>Tus datos son los siguientes:<br>Usuario: {$row['usuario']}<br>Contraseña: {$row['clave']} <br><br> Muchas gracias por elegir nuestros servicios!!! <strong><br><br><br>Ing. German Micco <br> Analista de Sistemas <br> germanmicco10@gmail.com</strong><br> ESTA ES UNA CUENTA NO MONITOREADA, POR FAVOR, ABSTENGASE DE RESPONDER O HACER LLAMADOS A NOMBRES DE ESTA CUENTA, SI NECESITA PRESENTAR ALGUN RECLAMO O REQUERIMIENTO, POR FAVOR HACERLO A TRAVES DE LA APLICACIÓN OFICIAL DE CONTRUMECA";

            // Acá validamos si el email no es enviado, que muestre el error
            if(!$mail->send()){
                echo 'El correo no pudo ser enviado';
                echo 'Error: ' .$mail->ErrorInfo;
            // En caso contrario, que muestre el mensaje de envío exitoso
            } else {
                echo 'Tu contraseña ha sido enviada correctamente a tu correo';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

O igual que te comentó Bryro:

```
        // Acá validamos si el email es enviado, que muestre el mensaje de envío exitoso
        if($mail->send()){
            echo 'Tu contraseña ha sido enviada correctamente a tu correo';
        // En caso contrario, que muestre el error
        } else {
            echo 'El correo no pudo ser enviado';
            echo 'Error: ' .$mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
```